# Partial installation of redis-server causes apt-get to hang

Tags: apt, dpkg, redis

I'm still very much a novice when it comes to Linux as a whole, and I have no clue what's happening here.

I tried to install redis-server in order to integrate BLAST into my JBrowse install (program to search for nucleotide sequences, and a visual browser for displaying this data). When I used:

```
sudo apt-get install redis-server
```

The install hangs at

```
Setting up redis-server (2:3.0.6-1ubuntu0.3) ...
```

after giving the program 2 days to run, I killed the thread by first using

```
ps aux | grep apt
```

Which gives

```
perryg    7954  0.0  0.0  14224   924 pts/7    S+   01:57   0:00 grep --color=au                                                                                                                                                             to apt
root     38576  0.0  0.0  54792  3900 pts/3    S+   Dec14   0:00 sudo apt-get pu                                                                                                                                                             rge --auto-remove redis-server
root     38577  0.0  0.0 118568 80428 pts/3    S+   Dec14   1:29 apt-get purge -                                                                                                                                                             -auto-remove redis-server
```

I used

```
sudo kill 38577
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

-or-

```
sudo apt-get install --fix-missing
```

and it always hangs at

```
Setting up redis-server (2:3.0.6-1ubuntu0.3) ...
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am also experiencing this. I used strace to see what it was doing, its hanging in post-install. Still working on figuring it out

Comment: If I hear anything, I'll DM you ASAP. So far, no insight, and no resolution.

I'm considering just using another node in the short term, and then probably just wipe the drive and start anew.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and also unable to remove redis-server due to it hanging.

Comment: Michael Lenzen's solution below is a usable workaround until a proper solution is found.

Comment: Nope, Michael Lenzen's solution does not work for me: I don't have any init.d script, and after I purged redis*, I still cannot install redis...

Answer (score 3):

My solution was to kill all redis-server processes, and try the remove again.

```
ps aux | grep redis
```

And use `kill <pid>` or `kill -9 <pid>`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it turns out I already had an Redis installed (not from apt) and running by default. I removed the init script for the non-packaged redis:

```
$ sudo mv /etc/init.d/redis_#### /usr/local/src/redis-stable/
```

Then when I restarted I could successfully install/remove the redis-server package.

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue in general, but functions as a work-around until the root cause is solved. This worked fine for me for now.

Comment: @Cody Being quite new to this, do you know what can cause this to reoccur, as the root issue hasn't been resolved?

Also, are there any preventative steps that can be taken to prevent, or reduce it from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a bug : https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/3241

So the (temporary) solution is to edit /etc/redis/redis.conf
and remove the '::1' in the line:

```
bind 127.0.0.1 ::1
```

After that, you can start redis with systemctl or service.